# Why is $\pi_2(S^1 \vee S^2)$ not finitely generated?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is an exercise following a discussion of fibrations. preceding that there was a discussion of cofibrations and the long exact sequence of homotopy groups of a pair.   Any hints would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: For $n>1$, the $n$th homotopy group of a space is the same as the $n$th homotopy group of the universal cover.

Comment: And the $\pi_2$ of the cover is isomorphic to its $H_2$, which is easier to compute.

Comment: (Well, since the two are isomorphic, they are equally easy to compute...)

Comment: Here is an explicit calculation and answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675337/calculate-pi-2s2-vee-s1